# ValueError: max fee per gas less than block base fee - Brownie

Tags: python, brownie

I am getting the error "ValueError: max fee per gas less than block base fee" when I try to run the following script using Brownie. I think I figured out that when I send a transaction, I need to set a gas price equal or higher than the next block's base fee (although strangely I didn't run into this issue when I was working on another project recently). How do I fix this?

```
from brownie import FundMe, network, config, MockV3Aggregator
from scripts.helpfulscripts import get_account, deploy_mocks
from scripts.deploy import deploy_fund_me
from web3 import Web3

def fund():
    deploy_fund_me()
    fund_me = FundMe[-1]
    account = get_account()
    entrance_fee = fund_me.getEntranceFee()
    print(f"The current entrance fee is {entrance_fee}")
    print("Funding")
    fund_me.fund({"from": account, "value": entrance_fee})

def withdraw():
    fund_me = FundMe[-1]
    account = get_account()
    fund_me.withdraw({"from": account})

def main():
    fund()
    withdraw()
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll leave this up in case anyone else runs into this (particularly while doing PatrickC's python blockchain course). I figured out that the problem was that I was running anvil in another terminal and then I was trying to deploy on Brownie's development chain which uses the same RPC as anvil. As soon as I closed the terminal running anvil, it worked.